# Get all information from each table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Because of all products have different price of its different package, I have separated its table for each products.

```html
<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr c>
    <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product One</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>package</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2kg</td>
    <td>$10</td>
    <td>p2.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4kg</td>
    <td>$20</td>
    <td>p4.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6kg</td>
    <td>$30</td>
    <td>p6.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>8kg</td>
    <td>$40</td>
    <td>p8.jpg</td>
  </tr>
</table></br></br>

<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr c>
    <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product Two</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>package</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2kg</td>
    <td>$12</td>
    <td>p2.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4kg</td>
    <td>$14</td>
    <td>p4.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6kg</td>
    <td>$16</td>
    <td>p6.jpg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>8kg</td>
    <td>$18</td>
    <td>p8.jpg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want is to create a new table to collect the all products name: product one, product two, product three and product four.

```html
<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr c>
    <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product One</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Product One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Product Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Product 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Product Four</td>
  </tr>
</table></br></br>
```

My question now is how to get all information of all product by connecting the name of products.

I am going to create a drop-down selection for its package. when they select the package, the price will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is in coldfusion but i am sure there must be something similar in php

```
   <cfquery name="gtmyinfo" datasource="mydb">
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable
    </cfquery>

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product ID</div></td>
      <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product Name</div></td>
      <td colspan="4"><div align="center">Product Image</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <cfoutput query="gtmyinfo">
     <td colspan="4"><div align="center">#ProductID#</div></td>
     <td colspan="4"><div align="center">#ProductName#</div></td>
     <td colspan="4"><div align="center">#ProductImage#</div></td>
   </tr>
   </cfoutput>
```

the table will keep looping as long with as many rows of data their are in the query.

you can limit which data is called with the "where" tag in the query or with an if/else tag in the table.